# Systemd tasks and limit

Tags: systemd

First off: please don't flag this question as being for Stack Overflow (yes, Python is a major part of the context but my question is ultimately about Systemd)

I am currently writing a Python program that will sit on a server and be controlled through Systemd (enabled so it restarts if the server goes down, etc.). My concern is that the "Tasks" section of the `systemctl status` is continually increasing.

```
...
Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-08-26 18:31:12 UTC; 14min ago
Main PID: 1657 (python3)
Tasks: 178 (limit: 637)  <--
...
```

Extrapolating this information, it will take a little over 50mins (from service start) before the limit is reached. My question is not "why is my code broken", "how do I raise this limit" or the like. Instead my question is: what does Systemd consider a task and what will happen when the limit is reached (is a signal sent to kill the service, etc.)?

With this information, I hope to understand why my Python script has (what appears to be) a linear increase in the number of tasks (and subsequently fix this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[systemd.resource-control(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#TasksMax=N) gives us a hint:

> ```
>    TasksMax=N
>       Specify the maximum number of tasks that may be created in the unit. This 
>       ensures that the number of tasks accounted for the unit (see above) stays
>       below a specific limit. This either takes an absolute number of tasks or a
>       percentage value that is taken relative to the configured maximum number of 
>       tasks on the system. If assigned the special value "infinity", no tasks 
>       limit is applied. This controls the "pids.max" control group attribute. For
>       details about this control group attribute, see Process Number Controller[7].
>
>       The system default for this setting may be controlled with DefaultTasksMax= 
>       in systemd-system.conf(5).
> ```

So this limit is based on "pids.max".  PIDs are generated whenever your process calls [`fork()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) or [`clone()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html).  In the context of python, there is a [`os.fork()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork) which probably calls the system-call of the same name.  I'm not sure in which other situations `python` would make those system calls, but if you're not spawning hundreds of processes, then I expect it to be related to the number of spawned threads.

The man page references some good literature: [[7] Process Number Controller](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/pids.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I thought Python threads were too high to be assigned PIDs but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45188576) seems to suggest otherwise. Again, thank you for your answer as I reviewed the conditions for thread creation and found them to be horribly negligent.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this command to your scripts with: `systemctl restart yourproject.service`

Explanation: With `systemctl restart`, your project always has a fresh task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Depending on the contents of the script this could interfere with the intended operation. Also the script would need to run as root to call systemctl.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped. Apparently this is a counter that gets "filled up" after a while and as such is a great hindrance to the task scheduler I'm using to execute a lot of jobs on a daily basis.